# Conversión fallida para una fecha en SQL

Tags: sql, date, base-de-datos

Los tipos de datos estan bien idCita es varchar(10), tipo varchar(40), fecha date.
Alguien podria ayudarme?

```
use EPS;

insert into citas (idCita, tipo, fecha) values (100, 'Medica', '20/05/2020');
```

y este es el error que me sale

`Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: El formato que insertas no es el correcto, no va año mes y día

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
insert into citas (idCita, tipo, fecha) values (100, 'Medica', '2020-05-20');
```

También deberías contemplar que `idCita` sea `AUTO_INCREMENT` y dejar que el servidor vaya asignando valores de forma autónoma.

```
ALTER TABLE citas CHANGE idCita idCita INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Quedando la inserción:

```
insert into citas (tipo, fecha) values ('Medica', '2020-05-20');
```

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)